# Copy colored cells in another spreadsheet to current spreadsheet

Tags: vba

What I want to do is to copy the same range("F2: F403") in the worksheetB in the workbookB
to the same range("F2:F403") in worksheet A in ThisWorkBook if the cells in worksheetB
is colored in green(colorIndex=4).
Otherwise, no doing copying.

I am pretty new in VBA(not used for one year).
Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub fillgreen()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim SUD_F As Range, S_Cell As Range, U_Cell As Range, Usage_F As Range
    Dim i As Variant

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WorksheetA")
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsx").Worksheets("WorksheetB")

    With ws1
        Set SUD_F = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("F2: F403")
    End With

    With ws2
        Set Usage_F =_
        Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsx").Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("F2: F403")
    End With

    ' now fill the Usage_F green value to SUD_F

    For i = 2 To 403
        If Usage_F.Cells(i, "F").Value.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            SUD_F.Cells(i, "F").Value = Usage_F.Cells(i, "F").Value
        Else
            SUD_F.Cells(i, "F").Value = SUD_F.Cells(i, "F").Value

    End If
    Next i


    End Sub
```

Comment: Please try to *indent* code when posting  - non-indented code is more difficult (for us *and* you) to follow.  Your With blocks are not doing anything - you can just remove the With...End With

Comment: @TimWilliams I am so sorry for the miss. I would edit that right away, I indented with Python and C++, I did not touch vba too long..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Tim continuous help, and I know it is not easy to see the problem off hand. After searching for some other tutorial outside, I succeeded with the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Color()

Dim Workbook As ThisWorkbook
Dim workksheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Variant
Dim S_range, U_range As Range
Dim rw As Range

Set S_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journals with no use").Range("F2:F403")
Set U_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Use").Range("F2: F403")

For i = 2 To 403
    If U_range.Cells.Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180) Then
        S_range.Cells.Rows(i).Value = U_range.Cells.Rows(i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe more like this:

```
Sub fillgreen()

    Dim SUD_F As Range, Usage_F As Range
    Dim i As Long, v

    Set SUD_F = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("F2:F403")
    Set Usage_F = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsx").Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("F2:F403")

    For i = 1 To Usage_F.Cells.Count

        If Usage_F.Cells(i, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            SUD_F.Cells(i, "F").Value = Usage_F.Cells(i, "F").Value
        Else
            SUD_F.Cells(i, "F").Value = SUD_F.Cells(i, "F").Value '??
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I would try that tomorrow( not available right now) and if this solved that I would mark it as answer. Just I wonder why i starts with 1? Maybe I can change that to For i = 2 to 403 if your i refers to row index as I planned to.Maybe that does not matter.

Comment: I assumed that `UsageF` was your actual data (excluding headers) and that you'd want to loop over all the rows in that data.   If Row 2 has headers then feel free to adjust the starting row accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much! There was no error nor doing anything.. I am trying to see where has been wrong

Comment: Is your coloring because of Conditional Formatting?

Comment: I am not super sure, but I recorded Macro and see the green color is RGB(198, 224, 280), so I set this, and I tried to use ".copy" as what I tried was actually copy all the green cells to another worksheet and the range and index are the same. This should be doable. Unfortunately, I am still struggling.

Comment: If you put breakpoints on the lines in the `If` test do they get hit?  Select one of your green cells, then in the Immediate pane enter `? Selection.Interior.ColorIndex` and press Enter.  What is the result?

Comment: If you use RGB then make sure to use `Interior.Color` and not `ColorIndex`